# How do you deploy a .war running JBoss as a Service on Windows XP?

Tags: jboss, service, war

Jboss 4.2.0A

Is there a /server directory that I need to change or something?

It's usually because I run ant build and it does all that fun stuff for me. seems like using the service method i have to move it manually... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any particular problem when putting the war in `server/default/deploy`?